# O365 Patterns and Practices JavaScript Injection / Embed JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a vanilla O365 developer site which I'm deploying the app in the JavaScriptInjection example here - https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3658/02%20Managing%20site%20settings%20using%20app%20model/Completed%20Projects/JavaScriptInjection

I'm getting pretty inconsistent behaviour across IE 11, Chrome and Firefox.

For example if I click on the Home link on the left navigation I (almost always) **don't** see the message
[image]

If I click on the browser refresh icon I (almost always) do see the message.

[image]

In Chrome, it appears to work a bit better, but still not seeing the message consistently.

I'm assuming there is something missing from the example, I've tried adding 
`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to the scenario.js file without success.

Is anyone using this example consistently, do I need to update something?

Comment: You should probably ask this question in the office 365 developer network on yammer as well, the Pnp has it's own group there

Comment: Does the [Minimal Download Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544.aspx) kick in (do you have a hash in the url) when the script does not run?

Comment: If a refresh fixes it it sounds like a client-side caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the sample has been updated and renamed here -https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EmbedJavaScript

This sample is the one I had issues with, and therefore shouldnt be used.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3658/02%20Managing%20site%20settings%20using%20app%20model/Completed%20Projects/JavaScriptInjection

I did a quick compare of the `scenario1.js` file that is embedded in the code to see the difference.

These are the differences.

[image: scenario1.js differences]

All I did to fix the 'old' sample was copy the 'new' scenario1.js into the solution.

Reasons for the error are related to Minimal Download Strategy `MDS` and ensuring script is available using `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`